# php foreach checkbox checked add to $emailto

Tags: php, email, post, foreach

My form needs to have multiple email addresses. I have a form that has checkboxes. Every checkbox that is checked should be added to where the emails' recepient list. The data is getting passed correctly, I know this because if I echo it out on a new page it will correctly show each of the values. I'm using `$_POST`.

The variable to append is called `$email_to`.
It gets sent in: `@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);`

With a static `$email_to` value the form functions properly and emails the data.

So far I've tried
 `foreach($_POST['rep'] as $rep_num) { $emailto = $rep_num;}`
 `foreach($_POST['rep'] as $rep_num[]) { $emailto = $rep_num[];}`

I think the foreach is lacking something, but I can't figure out what. It can echo it out fine, but not store it in a variable. Can anyone point me in the direction of what I need to?

**HTML**

```
<div class="clearfix email_boxes">
        <input type="checkbox" name="rep[]" value="02@address.com,">Lorem Ipsum 01
        <input type="checkbox" name="rep[]" value="02@address.com,">Lorem Ipsum 02
        <input type="checkbox" name="rep[]" value="03@address.com,">Lorem Ipsum 03
</div>
```

Comment: It might be the commas in your input values. Try removing them.

Comment: are you only getting the last email in $rep_num ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- the commas are needed to separate the addresses. Even with a single static address with a comma at the end, such as `abcd123.site.com,` the form will send.

Comment: @AdilMahmudChoudhury none of the recepients receive the form, the `foreach` isn't working correctly. I think it needs something else.

Comment: @GhostEcho Yes I'm aware of that, but mail/PHP don't see it that way. They will be seperated once the `foreach` kicks in and assigns it to the `to:` field. Theoretically, that's what's "supposed" to happen. Leaving the last one with a comma, will surely throw an error.

Comment: Actually, you could have used `foreach($_POST['rep'] as $to) { mail($to, $email_subject, $email_message); }` which I tested and worked without the commas in the values. @GhostEcho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `array_push` or the shorthand square brackets `[]` to add items to an array.

For example

```
$emails = array();
foreach($_POST['rep'] as $email) {
   // Each $email is added as the next array entry, using [] 
   $emails[] = $email; 
}

// Convert the array to a comma separated string
$recipients = implode(',', $emails);

mail($recipients, $subject, $message);
```

Comment: that's it! I knew it was missing something. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With a slight modification to what you already had:

You're welcome to use it. (pre-tested)

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$email = "yourEmail@example.com";
$email_subject = "Subject here";
$email_message = "The message";

$headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
"Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

foreach($_POST['rep'] as $to) {
mail($to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
}

} // ending brace for if(isset($_POST['submit']))

?>

<form method="post" action="">

<div class="clearfix email_boxes">
<input type="checkbox" name="rep[]" value="email_1@example.com">Lorem Ipsum 01
<input type="checkbox" name="rep[]" value="email_2@example.com">Lorem Ipsum 02
<input type="checkbox" name="rep[]" value="email_3@example.com">Lorem Ipsum 03
</div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Email to Users">

</form>
```

Comment: So, the difference in this one is wrapping the `foreach` around the `@mail` command. Also, if you're a recepient,  none of the other recepients appear in your 'To:' section. It all still works, but you can't see who else it was mailed to. This could be good, or bad, depending on what you want them to see. Thanks.

Comment: @GhostEcho Exactly; depending which way you look at it. A single-sent email is less likely to be taken as SPAM, and others won't see a list of many, which also is not suggested. I use a similar fashion from a DB that comes in handy. Some ISP/hosting do not allow for mass mailing. And, you're welcome, cheers.

Comment: Good to know, that might be valuable information in the future.

Comment: @GhostEcho I hope it serves you well.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST['rep'] as $rep_num) { $emailto = $rep_num;}
```

Here you are putting all emails in $emailto variable. So every time the loops run it erase the old one and save the new one. So at the end you are getting the last email address.

So you can use an array to save the email address. and then send email one by one. You can use a counter inside your loop to check how many times your loop run and then you can use that counter as a loop counter for sending email.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($_POST['rep'] as $key => $rep_num) {
     $emailto = $rep_num;
}
```

Att.